# Accidentally cleaned all of my Puppet certificates

Tags: ssl, puppet

So I'm a Puppet noob, and I foolishly did a `cert clean --all`. I'm now in the process of re-doing all of the certificates but I have a problem.

So what I've tried to do to re-create the master certificate is stop the puppet service, back-up and deleted the ssh directory on the master (/var/lib/puppet/ssh for me), then I ran the following command to recreate the master certificates: -

```
puppet master --verbose --no-daemonise
```

Then I start the puppet service again.

However, then when I try and sign a client (after cleaning out the SSL directory on the client side), when I run  `puppet agent --test` I get the following error:-

> Error: Could not request certificate: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect

Or sometimes: -

> Error: Could not request certificate: Connection refused - connect(2)

Does anybody know what's causing these errors? Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's puppet version 3.6 by the way.

Comment: 1. When you say ssh directory, do you mean ssl directory? 2. 3.6 is long obsolete. You may want to start over with a supported version.

Comment: Ah yes, I meant ssl. Yeah, I realise it's pretty old, but I'm just trying to get it working as it was again at the moment.

Comment: Okay, a restart of the server fixed the issue. I'm an idiot. I'll skulk back to my hole now. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh I just realized you said you restarted the `puppet` service and not the `puppetserver` service. That explains a lot. If I really could do anything for you, it would be to exhort you to use a supported version of Puppet.